# Why do black bodies or black colored bodies cool down faster than white ones?

Tags: visible-light, solid-state-physics, material-science, thermal-radiation

Recently, I found an exercise in which a graph was shown with the variation of temperature of two painted cans as they received sunlight. 
 One of the questions was "Which of these two bodies will cool down faster?". I thought it was the white can and for my surprise i found out I was wrong. 
 Can someone explain me why?

Comment: have a look here, emissivity and absorptivity  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity#Absorptivity

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask  why does it exists this equivalence in emission and absorption  (in terms of particles interactions)?

Comment: it is a long thermodynamic argument that has to do also with black body radiation  see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/absrad.html .black body is a quantum phenomenon . the argument in the link ends up also with photon arguments

Comment: Your intuition is right. White paint has an emissivity that is very similar to that of black paint in the wavelength region where it matters - in the thermal infrared, with wavelengths around 10 um. So both radiate approximately the same amount, and the black absorbs more from visible light, so the black one stays warm longer.

Comment: Pieter, I'm sorry. I did not quite understand your explanation. It contradicts the info on the comments below. Can yoy clear your point to me?